# SQL - Select doesn't retrieve results

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I'm using `sqlsrv_num_rows` in order to check if a user exists in the DB.

When i'm running the query in my DB i'm getting 1 result, but in my PHP I'm not getting anything (`echo` doesn't print anything). Why is that?

```php
$query = "SELECT TOP 1 id, tourOp FROM users WHERE (valid = 1) AND (email = '".trim($_POST['email'])."') AND (password = '".trim($_POST['password'])."')";
$stmt  = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $query);      

echo "num: ".sqlsrv_num_rows( $stmt );

if (!sqlsrv_num_rows( $stmt )) {
    return (false); 
} else {

}
```

**Example query**

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 id, name FROM users WHERE (valid = 1) AND (email = 'roi@some_email.com') AND (password = '8521')
```

I'm using PHP and MSSQL.

Comment: I add `if ($stmt === false){
  echo "<pre>";print_r( sqlsrv_errors()); echo "</pre>";
  exit;
 } ` but no new results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanations:

- Function `sqlsrv_num_rows()` requires a client-side, static, or keyset cursor, and will return `false` if you use a forward cursor or a dynamic cursor (the default cursor is forward cursor). Execute `sqlsrv_query()` with additional `$options` parameter and set the appropriate cursor type with `"Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET`
- Use parameterized statements. Function `sqlsrv_query()` does both statement preparation and statement execution and can be used to execute parameterized queries.
- If you want to check if the result set has one or more rows, you may use `sqlsrv_has_rows()`.

Example, based on your code:

```
<?php
$query = "
    SELECT TOP 1 id, tourOp 
    FROM users 
    WHERE (valid = 1) AND (email = ?) AND (password = ?)";
$params = array(trim($_POST['email']), trim($_POST['password']));
$options = array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $query, $params, $options);      
if ($exec === false){
    echo print_r( sqlsrv_errors()); 
    echo "<br>";
    return (false);
}

$count = sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt);
if ($count === false) {
    echo print_r( sqlsrv_errors()); 
    echo "<br>";
    return (false);
} else {
    echo "num: ".$count;
}
?>
```

Notes:

Do not send user credentials in plain text.

Comment: Thank you. you help me a lot :)