# How to get the number of rows that my query returned?

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I have a php page connected with sqlServer and I want to know number of rows that my query return ,but I can't with this code !!

Maybe I should modify something !! please any help??

```
$serverName="DESKTOP-T5SLVUB\SQL2008R2";
$connectionInfo=array("Database"=>"Netos_DB","UID"=>"sa","PWD"=>"123");
$conn=sqlsrv_connect($serverName,$connectionInfo);


$json = file_get_contents('php://input');

$obj = json_decode($json,true);

$mois = $obj['mois'];

 $annee = $obj['annee'];
if( $conn === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
else{
 $sql = "select TOP 80* from V502_client where Mois=? and Annee=?";

    $params=array(5 ,2015);
   $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql ,$params );

    $row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows( $stmt );

    if ($row_count === false)
   echo "Error in retrieveing row count.";
else
   echo $row_count;

}

?>
```

Comment: Use a client-side cursor. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59037149/sql-select-doesnt-retrieve-results/59037450#59037450) for more information.

Comment: You should return Selcet count(*) from v502_client where mois=? and annee=? ;